# Cannot redeclare class Exception

Tags: php

I get this error, strangely, by this code

```
namespace \Models\Game;

class Exception extends \Exception {

}
```

I thought the purpose of namespaces was to eliminate ambiguous class names, and I was expecting I would be able to declare such a class. Why can't I create a class named Exception even though it's not in the root namespace?

Comment: Could you post the lines this class includes? How does the structure look? If you're doing include() and class is called more than once, it'll throw error. If this is the case, you could try require_once() or include_once(). Please give more details if you're able to.

Comment: That is the class, there's nothing inside it. I just created it and refreshed. The error is occurring on the line where the closing bracket is, if that makes any sense.

Comment: Oh god why.. @Clive Thanks! Care to post an answer, explaining why that caused an error?

Comment: namespaces I guess want work if you are using names as the standard PHP lib names like Exception, Iterator, etc

Comment: @php_nub_qq Looks like someone's already done it, just go with that one :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be `namespace Models\Game`:

```
namespace Models\Game;

class Exception extends \Exception {
    public function __toString(){ return 'hello';}
}

$e = new Exception;

// prints hello
var_dump($e -> __toString());
```